# 'ilike' keyword not working with spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am learning apache-spark. And what seems confusing is,

this command works

`results = spark.sql("select * from df_sql_view where name LIKE '%i%'")`

but this throws an error

`results = spark.sql("select * from df_sql_view where name ILIKE '%i%'")`

```
ParseException: 
mismatched input 'ILIKE' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 1, pos 37)

== SQL ==
select * from df_sql_view where name ILIKE '%i%'
-------------------------------------^^^
```

Could someone please help me understand why and how to resolve it. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spark SQL only support [`like`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#like) and [`rlike`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#rlike). So you'd want to use `rlike` with proper regex to replace `ilike`

Comment: worked. thank you. :) but why is it so? is rlike a more useful function or the developers of spark just chose not to add ilike?

Comment: Actually, `ilike` was added in 3.3.0: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#ilike. For example, it worked for me in 3.3.1 (vs. broken in 3.2.3).

Comment: What throws some people off, like myself initially is that `LIKE` with one `%` placeholder is case insensitive (at the moment), but when there are more placeholders it starts being fussy about case.